# Error using NAV 2013 R2 Webservice with page 81 Gen_ Journal Line

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I'm building a C# application to read some bank statement files and create some registries in Gen_ Journal Line table.

I've configured page 81 Gen_ Journal Line as webservice and I'm accessing through oData interface.

I'm getting the error :
**Primary keyvalue(s) Journal_Batch_Name, Journal_Template_Name, Line_No are missing in insert command. Make sure that all primary keys on the page are backed by a control in order to be set**

I've installed NAV 2013 R2 with the demo database in my laptop, configured that same Webservice and it' works with the same exact code.

But in the client's NAV server I get the above error.

I'm printing the mentioned fields before calling nav.SaveChanges() and the fields have the expected values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish a standard general journal (page 39), you can't add a line via web a service.

When you call your code that creates a new line in the journal, primary key fields should be displayed on the page, otherwise their values are unpredictable. I don't know why the code behaves differently on your laptop and the server, but I would assume that your laptop experience would be irreproducible. If you create another batch in the same general journal and try to insert several lines in different batches through the web service, it won't work.

I would suggest choosing another way. You could create another page with fields you need to fill (including primary key fields) and expose it as a web service (OData or SOAP), or create a codeunit that would perform the task and expose its method as a SOAP service.

Comment: Most likely, you have different results because of different builds. This error message you see on the server was added in cumulative update 10. Update your laptop build to CU10, and the result will be aligned.

Comment: Alexander, When I call the code I fill the primary key fields. That's why it works in my laptop and the lines are created in the right batch.

Comment: Either way, I'm going to install CU10 in my laptop, just to be sure.

Comment: It's a confusion here. Seems, this error message was deleted again in CU 17 for 2013 R2, and the bug was properly fixed. Then, hopefully, all you need to do is to update your server installation to the latest build.